# Running periodic django tasks inside docker

Tags: django, docker, cron, celery, periodic-task

I have a django management-command to scrape a site and update the database accordingly. I plan to run this task every 10 mins continuously. Previously I had written cronjobs to update the database during development but now in production, I am using Docker where I can only run one CMD command which I am using for runserver.

```
RUN python manage.py makemigrations

RUN python manage.py migrate

CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:5000" ]

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN (crontab -e ; "python manage.py update_db >> /var/log/cron.log") | crontab

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

I tried something like this and then came to know we cant have 2 CMD in a Dockerfile. I looked at celery but in that case, as well I would have to run that command and would have 2 CMD in a Dockerfile.

What would be the best approach in this situation as I am very new to Docker and writing cronjobs.

Thanks.

Comment: You will almost certainly have to run 2 separate containers. You can override the command when you run the container if you wish to use the same image with different commands

Comment: @IainShelvington Okay. Thanks. I will look into that